# How to get rid of the vala compilation warning "copying delegates is discouraged" in the right way?

Tags: vala

I get the above mentioned warning in the following code:

```
[DBus (name = "example.Hello")]
public class HelloDbusServer : Object {
    private bool is_test = false;
    public HelloDbusServer.test() {
        is_test = true;
    }
    [DBus (name = "sayHello")]
    public string say_hello() {
        if (is_test) {
            return "hello (test)";
        }
        return "hello";
    }
}
void on_bus_aquired(DBusConnection conn) {
    try {
        conn.register_object ("/example/Hello", new HelloDbusServer());
    } catch (IOError e) {
        stderr.printf ("Could not register dbus service!\n");
        Posix.exit(1);
    }
}
void on_bus_aquired_test(DBusConnection conn) {
    try {
        conn.register_object ("/example/Hello", new HelloDbusServer.test());
    } catch (IOError e) {
        stderr.printf ("Could not register dbus service!\n");
        Posix.exit(1);
    }
}
void on_bus_name_lost(DBusConnection conn) {
    stderr.printf ("Could not aquire dbus name!\n");
    Posix.exit(2);
}
void main (string[] args) {
    BusType bt = BusType.SYSTEM;
    BusAcquiredCallback cb = on_bus_aquired;
    if ((args.length > 1) && (args[1] == "test"))
    {
        bt = BusType.SESSION;
        cb = on_bus_aquired_test;
        stderr.printf ("Running in test mode on session bus.\n");
    }
    Bus.own_name (bt, "example.Hello", BusNameOwnerFlags.NONE,
                  cb,
                  () => {},
                  on_bus_name_lost);
    new MainLoop().run();
}
```

The warning pops up for the variable "cb" at the method call "Bus.own_name (bt, "example.Hello", BusNameOwnerFlags.NONE, cb, () => {}, on_bus_name_lost)".

I already searched for a solution and tried all kinds of things with "owned" and closures as mentioned in some tips in the net, but I did not manage to fix this issue.

Thanks for any help.

---

Thank you for the answer #1.
I tried both solutions already.

Using "(owned)" I got this warning:

```
    /.../helloFromDBus.vala.c: In function ‘_vala_main’:
    /.../helloFromDBus.vala.c:402:2: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘g_cclosure_new’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
    /usr/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gclosure.h:206:11: note: expected ‘GClosureNotify’ but argument is of type ‘GDestroyNotify’
```

I did not realy understand the warning.
A try was fixing the signature of the "on_bus_aquired..." method to be in line with the "BusAcquiredCallback" delegate.
I added "string name" as second parameter.  Then I got the same warning as above.

Using "(con) => { cb (con); }" lead to the error:

```
    helloFromDBus.vala:50.18-50.25: error: Too few arguments, method `GLib.BusAcquiredCallback' does not take 1 arguments
              (con) => { cb (con); },
```

Fixing the signature as mention above and using "(con, name) => { cb (con, name); }" gave the following warning:

```
    /.../helloFromDBus.vala.c: In function ‘_vala_main’:
    /.../helloFromDBus.vala.c:448:2: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘g_cclosure_new’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
    /usr/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gclosure.h:206:11: note: expected ‘GClosureNotify’ but argument is of type ‘void (*)(void *)’
```

I did not realy understand this warning either.

Any help to fix these warning?

Comment: What exactly have you tried?

Comment: Don't worry about those warnings.  It's just the C compiler whining, it should work fine.  If you want, you can pass -X -w to valac to disable warnings from the C compiler.  https://live.gnome.org/Vala/FAQ#How_can_I_fix_CC_warnings.3F

Answer (score 4):

The best way is usually to transfer your reference using `(owned)`:

```
Bus.own_name (bt,
              "example.Hello",
              BusNameOwnerFlags.NONE,
              (owned) cb,
              () => {},
              on_bus_name_lost);
```

After which `cb` will be `null`.

If that's not acceptable (because you still need your copy of `cb` for something), you can wrap the callback in a closure:

```
Bus.own_name (bt,
              "example.Hello",
              BusNameOwnerFlags.NONE,
              (con, name) => { cb (con, name); },
              () => {},
              on_bus_name_lost);
```

The reason copying is discouraged is that the context information (user_data at the C level) isn't reference counted, so you can't really have two owned references to it at the same time.